# @async not working as expected in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to make parallel rest calls.

I have setup the executor like this in the class itself.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
```

and i have passed it into my completable Future like this.

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = urls.stream()
                .map( url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> function(url,start), executor))
                .toList();
```

This works as expected. [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPP8t.png)

Now when I try using the @async annotation, It does not work as expected, I don't have an executor object to pass it with async call and so it does not use my executor. I am new to springboot so I am not sure exactly how beans work.

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = urls.stream()
                .map( url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> function(url,start)))
                .toList();
```

and this is my async config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration  {
    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3if.png)

How do I solve this ?

Comment: Here is a spring guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/  on how to use @Async with CompletableFuture

Answer (score 1):

`@EnableAsync` should be annotated at the class where `@Async` used, or the `MainApplication`.

e.g.

```
@Service
@EnableAsync
public class TestService{

  @Async
  public void doAsync() {
    // ...
  }

}
```